# Trying to limit the number of submissions from a form

Tags: php, mysql

So essentially the logged in user should only be able to submit their preferences once and then edit them from the table.

```
if(isset($_POST['userPrefSave'])){
    $studetnPrefId=$_POST['studentPrefId'];
    $studentId=$_POST['studentId'];

    $result= limitUserPref($studentPrefId,$studentId);
    //print_r($result);
    if(isset($result)< 1){
    $studentPrefId=$_POST['studentPrefId'];
    $studentId=$_POST['studentId'];
    $english=$_POST['english'];
    $math=$_POST['math'];
    $science=$_POST['science'];
    $history=$_POST['history'];
    $oralComm=$_POST['oralComm'];
    $pe=$_POST['pe'];
    $health=$_POST['health'];
    $art=$_POST['art'];
    $electives=$_POST['electives'];
    setUserPref($studentPrefId, $studentId, $english, $math, $science, $history, $oralComm, $pe, $health, $art, $electives);

    header ("Location: userpref.php");
}
}
```

This is the controller ^^^

```
function setUserPref($studentPrefId, $studentId, $english, $math,               $science, $history, $oralcomm, $pe, $health, $art, $electives){
    DB::insertUpdate('student_pref', array(
    'student_pref_id'=>$studentPrefId
    ,'student_id'=>$studentId
    ,'english'=>$english
    ,'math'=>$math
    ,'science'=>$science
    ,'history'=>$history
    ,'oral_comm'=>$oralcomm
    ,'pe'=>$pe
    ,'health'=>$health
    ,'art'=>$art
    ,'electives'=>$electives));
}
function getStudentPref($studentID){
    return DB::query("SELECT * FROM student_pref WHERE student_id = %d", $studentID);
}

function limitUserPref($studentPrefId, $studentId) {
   return DB::query("SELECT * FROM student_pref WHERE student_pref_id = %d and student-id= %d", $studentPrefId, $studentId);

}
```

Functions^^^

I don't know what is wrong thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to limit number of submissions for a php form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281463/is-there-a-way-to-limit-number-of-submissions-for-a-php-form)

Comment: I've read that but it didn't do exactly what I needed I played around with it some but I couldn't arrive at what I needed

Comment: Also I don't want the page to die because the user has a table on that page where they can edit the information stored

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that the check you are doing is wrong.
isset() will determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

More info about php isset http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

You are checking for will always be true
`if(isset($result)< 1){`

Try the following

```
if(isset($_POST['userPrefSave'])){
    $studetnPrefId=$_POST['studentPrefId'];
    $studentId=$_POST['studentId'];

    $result= limitUserPref($studentPrefId,$studentId);
    //print_r($result);
    if(count($result) < 1){
    $studentPrefId=$_POST['studentPrefId'];
    $studentId=$_POST['studentId'];
    $english=$_POST['english'];
    $math=$_POST['math'];
    $science=$_POST['science'];
    $history=$_POST['history'];
    $oralComm=$_POST['oralComm'];
    $pe=$_POST['pe'];
    $health=$_POST['health'];
    $art=$_POST['art'];
    $electives=$_POST['electives'];
    setUserPref($studentPrefId, $studentId, $english, $math, $science,     $history, $oralComm, $pe, $health, $art, $electives);

header ("Location: userpref.php");
}
}
```

Comment: can you check the $result variable and what is it returning on the first submit, and what on the second? you might need to try with count($result)

Comment: regardless of where I print it nothing happens

Comment: then its probably empty the first time it load, try the code using count($result) instead

Comment: I got it to do something but it loads into my user-controller and not back into the userpref page there were a couple syntax errors but they were found and edited. Do you know how to prevent it from loading into the controller?